# How to include a library module multiple times into multiple library modules in the same app project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, realm, dex

I have a project structure as:
- app module
- multiple library modules..
- ...
- common library module (commonlib) consumed by the library modules above^ (has realm (compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.2') included as dependency)

now the commonlib is included as dependency in many modules and when I tried to run the project then I got the multiple dex files found error:

```
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModule;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/user/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Can anyone help me in how I can include the realm library but at the same time include it and the commonlib module in all the dependent modules as well? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks some of your library projects haven't defined their Schemas as library modules. If they do not, they will also create the file `DefaultRealmModule` which is why you get the conflict in the app project.

All your libraries should have a class that looks something like this:

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class MyLibraryModule() {

}
```

You can read more how to include Realm in both library and app projects here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas

Comment: yeah, I figured it out..anyhow. I'll mark it as the only answer for now. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @Christian This link doesn't seem to work anymore